# How to add custom field in Premium items Module in Shopware 5?

Tags: custom-fields, shopware

I am new in Shopware 5. I want to create custom field in Premium item module.
Please check the screenshot.

I have checked there is no any attribute table for Premium items.

Please tell me how I can create custom field here: [image: Screenshot illustrating where to add a maximum order value field]

Comment: Cross-Post: https://forum.shopware.com/t/how-to-create-some-fields-in-premium-items-module/93964/2

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention what you tried so far, so I will give you some basic information how to start. Feel free to come back with more questions.

### Adding the field `endPrice` to the detail view

The component you want to extend is `Shopware.apps.Premium.view.premium.Detail`.

You can add your new field, with similar code as the [startPrice field](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/fea66e73b5f6d57bb7cbac95d3d1b1329a03efd8/themes/Backend/ExtJs/backend/premium/view/premium/detail.js#L116).

See the developer guide on [backend extensions](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/backend-extension/#example-#1:-simple-extension). This will guide you trough the steps required to extend the detail window. (more information about [detail windows is also available](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/backend-components/detail/))

### Extending JS Model / Controller

Basically I recommend to full text search through `https://github.com/shopware/shopware/tree/5.7/themes/Backend/ExtJs/backend/premium` for `startPrice`. This will give you a hint what else to extend, to be able to persist your new field `endPrice`.

### Implementing the storage logic

You also need to implement the logic so that the setting actually will be saved. This core code is in [`Premium.php`](https://%20https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.7/engine/Shopware/Models/Premium/Premium.php) - there is a special formatting for start-price:

```
$params['startPrice'] = str_replace(',', '.', $params['startPrice']);
```

which you [might do via a hook](https://developers.shopware.com/blog/2015/06/09/understanding-the-shopware-hook-system/).

The basic parameters are stored in `s_addon_premiums`, but you cannot extend the [core model](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.7/engine/Shopware/Models/Premium/Premium.php), so you might want to use workarounds as described in [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36625397/288568) to store the value of your new `endPrice` field.

### Adding the logic

Finally you can hook into [`sGetPremiums`](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/fea66e73b5f6d57bb7cbac95d3d1b1329a03efd8/engine/Shopware/Core/sMarketing.php#L305). You can use an `after` hook to remove those premium items which should not be added from the returned `$premiums` array, because the order exceeds the `endPrice`.